# How to execute code after a mail::queue call

Tags: php, email, laravel-4

I'm new to using the Laravel 4 framework, so my apologies if this is a noob question (it probably is..)

Okay so basically my situation is that I have a script that is supposed to send out an email with attachments. And after the email is sent, I need to delete the file(s) that were attached and sent in the email.

So far I have made the following code:

```
    Mail::queue('email-report', array('hotel'=>$hotel), function($message)use($hotel,$matchedFiles)
    {
      $emails = array_map('trim',explode(",",$hotel->group_emails));
      $message->setTo($emails);
      $message->subject($hotel->email_subject);
      $message->from($hotel->email_alias);
      $message->replyTo($hotel->email_alias);
      foreach($matchedFiles as $mf) {
        $message->attach($mf);
      }
    });
```

This works fine as far as sending the email with attachments.

Now for the part about deleting the files (path/to/file is what `$matchedFiles` is).  Now, I don't think I can just remove them after the call to `Mail::queue()`, since that puts the job in a queue to be executed later, so the files need to be there later, yes?

So I need to wait until the job in the queue is complete, and then delete the files, right? But, how?  I've been poking at the Laravel 4 docs and trying to google but I can't seem to figure out if there's some callback method I can put code in or what..

**edit**

Okay so I've been doing more reading and research and it seems one thing I can do is instead of use `Mail::queue()`, I use `Mail::send()` and then wrap that in a job handler class and then push the job handler class to `Queue::push()` .  So I'm going to try this and see if it works..I'm not sure how to translate that code above to a job handler class, particularly passing the extra variables to it, but it's a step forward.

Anyways... it seems like there should already be a built-in callback for this somehow, so maybe someone will yet comment/answer.

**edit 2**

Okay so I was able to get some code to execute by doing what I thought above:

```
$data = array(
  'view' => 'email-report',
  'hotel' => $hotel,
  'matchedFiles' => $matchedFiles
);

Queue::push(function($job) use ($data)
{

  $hotel = $data['hotel'];
  $matchedFiles = $data['matchedFiles'];

  Mail::send('email-report', array('hotel'=>$hotel), function($message)use($hotel,$matchedFiles)
  {
    $emails = array_map('trim',explode(",",$hotel->group_emails));
    $message->setTo($emails);
    $message->subject($hotel->email_subject);
    $message->from($hotel->email_alias);
    $message->replyTo($hotel->email_alias);
    foreach($matchedFiles as $mf) {
      $message->attach($mf);
    }
  });

  /* this doesn't work - permission issues
  foreach($matchedFiles as $mf) {
    //File::delete($mf);
    //unlink($mf);
  }
  */

  // test i used to see if i can make code execute in general. It works!
  DB::insert('insert into table (column1,column2,column3) values (?,?,?)',
             array(
               $job->getJobId(),
               $hotel->hotel_id,
               implode(',',$matchedFiles)
              )
            );


  $job->delete();

});
```

So this works in that I can still queue up email sending but get some code to execute after its done.  So I guess that solves my problem...maybe? Actually, I'm not sure if this *really* works, because I can't get the files to actually delete, because of permissions issues.

The files are uploaded to an ftp dir by, but laravel/php is being executed by a different user/group.  So I'm not sure how to deal with this.. the files are actually in subdirs of the `/path/to/ftp/location/` that the ftp user can create. So I can't just make `/path/to/ftp/location/` owned by laravel/php user/group, because the subdirs themselves are owned by the ftp user.  I also tried to add the user that laravel/php runs under into the same group as the ftp user's group, but this didn't work. I think it's because the dirs/files are being written as only writable by the ftp user, not the ftp user's group (maybe something to do with a sticky bit? I'm getting way over my head in all of this...).

So the only thing I can think of offhand is to create a web interface for the user to upload the files through there so that php writes the files to a directory and therefore can remove them.  But I can't really do this, because the files are actually uploaded via a 3rd party automated process that only accepts an ftp location to dump the files to.

So I'm not really sure what to do, short of giving laravel/php root access and I'm pretty sure that's a bad idea...

Comment: What type of queue did you set to use in the config? So currently is your problem in the queue or is this more about deleting the files afterwards?

Comment: @har2vey using `Mail::send()` wrapped in a `Queue::push()` as I showed in **update 2** works, so at this point the issue is about (lack of) permissions for deleting the files

Comment: so I understand it *is* a permissions issue.. I'm just not sure what's the best way to overcome it. I see 2 choices: 1) have the script (php) handle uploading/writing the files so that it is the owner (which I can't do because it's a 3rd party script that expects an ftp location to drop files to), or 2) give php root privs so that it can write (delete) the files regardless of owner (which sounds like a bad idea).  So I'm trying to figure out a feasible option #3, which so far I have been unable to do.

Comment: but since the original question was more immediately about laravel scripting and that is solved, and the current issue is a linux dir/file permission issue now, I think I should close this question and start a separate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the original question was how to execute some code after `Mail::queue()` does its thing. As per my **edit 2**, this answers my original question:

```
$data = array(
  'view' => 'email-report',
  'hotel' => $hotel,
  'matchedFiles' => $matchedFiles
);

Queue::push(function($job) use ($data)
{

  $hotel = $data['hotel'];
  $matchedFiles = $data['matchedFiles'];

  Mail::send('email-report', array('hotel'=>$hotel), function($message)use($hotel,$matchedFiles)
  {
    $emails = array_map('trim',explode(",",$hotel->group_emails));
    $message->setTo($emails);
    $message->subject($hotel->email_subject);
    $message->from($hotel->email_alias);
    $message->replyTo($hotel->email_alias);
    foreach($matchedFiles as $mf) {
      $message->attach($mf);
    }
  });

  /* this doesn't work - permission issues
  foreach($matchedFiles as $mf) {
    //File::delete($mf);
    //unlink($mf);
  }
  */

  // test i used to see if i can make code execute in general. It works!
  DB::insert('insert into table (column1,column2,column3) values (?,?,?)',
             array(
               $job->getJobId(),
               $hotel->hotel_id,
               implode(',',$matchedFiles)
              )
            );


  $job->delete();

});
```

Basically the answer is to instead use `Mail::send()` and wrap it in a `Queue:push()`.

Now I have a separate issue concerning file permissions vs. deleting files, so that will be for a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

in Laravel 9, can use `dispatch()` helper instead..

example:

```
use Mail, Storage, Log, Throwable;

dispatch(function () use($user, $pdf_name) {

    Mail::to($user->email)->send( new ReceiptMail($user, $pdf_name) );

    // can do anything here... for example delete files
    Storage::disk('temp')->delete($pdf_name);
    

})
->onQueue('email_1') //NOTE: can remove this line if you want to use default queue
->catch(function (Throwable $e) {

    Storage::disk('temp')->delete($pdf_name);
    Log::error($e);
    

});
```

Refer the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#queueing-closures) for more details.